# Displaying suggestions for an empty SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I have a `SearchView` widget in my action bar that is displaying the correct suggested search terms when the user enters one or more characters.

I would like to also display a (different) list of suggestions when the `SearchView` is empty, including before the user has entered any text.

So far it is working correctly when the user either enters text then deletes that text, and when the user taps the search icon to open the widget then taps on the search widget a second time once it is opened. To do this, I am using an `OnQueryTextListener` like so:

```
class SearchTextEnteredListener implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (newText.length() > 1) {
            // Set normal suggestions
            CursorAdapter searchadapter = new SearchSuggestionsAdapter(mContext, suggestions);
            mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(searchadapter);
        } else if (newText.length() == 1) {
            // Clear the displayed suggestions
            if(searchadapter != null && mSearchView != null){
                searchadapter.createAndChangeCursor(null);
            }
        } else {
            // Length = 0, show other suggestions
            CursorAdapter searchadapter = new SearchSuggestionsAdapter(mContext, otherSuggestions);
            mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(searchadapter);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

However, I would like the suggestions to popup as soon as the search widget is opened, instead of requiring a second tap like it does now. I have had no luck getting it to do so.

I have even tried manually finding the `SearchView`'s `AutoCompleteTextView` and calling `showDropDown()` when the `SearchView` gets focus (see below), but that didn't display the dropdown either.

```
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            int autoCompleteId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
            if (autoCompleteId == 0) {
                // We won't be able to find the view. Give up.
                return;
            }

            AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView) mSearchView.findViewById(autoCompleteId);
            if (autoCompleteView != null) {
                autoCompleteView.showDropDown();
            }
        }
    }

});
```

How can I make the search suggestions dropdown when the search widget is opened?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. I'm using the compat v7 SearchView and Cursor Loaders for querying in harmony with the Activity lifecycle.

```
// e.g in onCreateView in my Fragment, wire up the SearchView:
MenuItem searchMenuItem = toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.search_menu_item);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
// and setup listeners (implementation is shown later)
searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
// then raid the SearchView so search begins on 0 chars!
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(0);
// and set the suggestions adapter so we can use a Loader to do the queries
SuggestionCursorAdapter suggestionCursorAdapter = new SuggestionCursorAdapter(getContext(), null, 0);
searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(suggestionAdapter);
```

Here are the implementations of the listeners:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String userInput) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userInput.trim())) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextChange: empty userInput");
        // The argument to the loader is null so your query should return all suggestions
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(SEARCH_VIEW_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        return true;
    }

    userInput = userInput.trim();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("USER_INPUT", userInput);
    // The argument contains the users input so your query should use a LIKE to find matching suggestions
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(SEARCH_VIEW_LOADER_ID, args, this);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onClose() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
    Cursor c = searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getCursor();
    final String suggestion = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("some_column_name"));
    Log.d(TAG, "onSuggestionClick: position: " + position + " suggestion: " + suggestion);
    return true;
}
```

One additional detail, my SuggestionCursorAdapter extends CursorAdaptor and overrides the following method to prevent: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery

```
@Override
public void changeCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
    newCursor.close();
}
```

It was a pain to work out so hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the search view

```
SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.viewSearch);
```

Make the `searchview` search on 0 text jst display the recent items

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView =  
searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(0);
```

Call the adapter on `searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener`

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            Cursor cursor = database.getSearchValue();
            Log.d("qqqqq", "onQuery: " + cursor.getCount());
            if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                String[] columns = new String[]{SuggestionSearchDatabase.FIELD_SEARCH};
                for (String data : new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(columns))) {
                    Log.i("dataCheck", "onClick: " + data);
                }
                Log.d("sss", "onClick: " + columns.length);
                int[] columnTextId = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};


                CursorSearchAdapter searchAdapter = new CursorSearchAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.view_searchview_layout, cursor, columns, columnTextId, 0);
                searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(searchAdapter);
            }
        }
    });
```